# When I Run my selenium C# Test case it fails and when i debug it, it passes, What is the problem?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am a little bit new to selenium with C#, I Have the following code

```
GlobalClass glc = new GlobalClass();

glc.waitForElementToBeClickable("select2-mainCorporateCustomers-results",7);
glc.randomClickULOption("select2-mainCorporateCustomers-results");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
glc.ClickDropdownbyText("MyDropDownName");
```

And below is the waitForElementToBeClickable method in the global class:

```
public void waitForElementToBeClickable(string elementID, double waitTime)
{
DefaultWait<IWebDriver> wait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>browserDriver);
   wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitTime);
   wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
   IWebElement searchResult = 
   wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id(elementID))); 
}
```

And below is my randomClickULOption method in the global class that randomly clicks on an item in the given list:

```
public void randomClickULOption(string ComboID)
    {            
        int itemsCount = 0;
        IWebElement comboName = browserDriver.FindElement(By.Id(ComboID));
        IList<IWebElement> listItems = 
        comboName.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
        foreach (IWebElement element in listItems)
        {
            itemsCount = itemsCount + 1;                
        }
        if (itemsCount==0)
        {
            Assert.Fail("No items in the combo box");
        }
        Random rand = new Random();
        int iSelect = rand.Next(itemsCount);
        //Selecting value from DropDownList
        listItems[iSelect].Click();            
    }
```

And below is my ClickDropdownbyText that opens the drop down menu by its text

```
public void ClickDropdownbyText(string text)
{
   var clickPath = "//span[contains(text(), '" + text + "')]";
   browserDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(clickPath)).Click();
}
```

My problem is that when I Run the test case it throws the following exception:

OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(), 'MyDropDownName')]"}

And when i put a break point on the following line in my test case:

```
glc.randomClickULOption("select2-mainCorporateCustomers-results");
```

and debug the code step by step the test case passes without any problem

Note i have tried to increase or decrease the wait time in the following line:

```
glc.waitForElementToBeClickable("select2-mainCorporateCustomers-results",3);
```

Additional note: The below line of code is not actually executed in the web page UI:

```
browserDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(clickPath)).Click();
```

I Mean this line must click in the list item before proceeding to the remaining code and this is not actually happen on the web page however it passes successfully when I Debug my code

But the problem still exist. So what is the problem ?

Comment: By how much did you extend the wait time? And what happens if you debug and simply continue execution instead of stepping?

Comment: I extended the time to be 10 seconds 
and when I debug and continue execution the test case pass successfully

Comment: i faced similar pb, so i use implicite wait and no mouse manipulation during the test execution. have you tried implicite wait? https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits

Comment: @H.Yuan Selenium contributors have strongly recommended against using implicit wait. You should instead use `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: Add a wait for clickable in `ClickDropdownbyText()` at the `.FindElement()` line... that's where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you all for your support, But all these solutions did not work, The problem still exist